# LibreOffice 4.2 for 14.10?

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice

I'm using Lubuntu 14.10. I want to know if the LibreOffice suite is available for Utopic as version 4.2.*. `apt-cache show libreoffice` lists only version 4.3.*

I understand that version 4.2.7 is the latest in the "still" channel which is for more conservative users but [this page](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-4-2) does not mention Utopic.

I guess I could download the archive from [libreoffice.org](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-still/).

Comment: Is there a problem with LibreOffice 4.3 that makes it unusable in Lubuntu 14.10?

Comment: No, it's usable. It's just that I realized that there are two "tracks", one of which is more conservative. Here's [a quote](http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/The-Document-Foundation-announces-LibreOffice-4-3-3-and-LibreOffice-4-2-7-td4127280.html): LibreOffice 4.3.3 "Fresh" is a stable release of the more advanced version of the software, and is targeted to users focusing on features.
LibreOffice 4.2.7 "Still" is a stable release of the more tested version of the software, and is targeted to users focusing on continuity.

Comment: As with any software, new versions are released sometimes with cutting edge tools or just newer tools.  Since this release is considered stable, I wouldn't worry about it unless you have a problem.